# Why isn't mypy finding my package?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I am in the directory containing my python package, and running `mypy -p <package-name>`, but it just errors out with "Can't find package".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't know mypy, but often you need to be in the directory above the package directory to make this sort of thing work.

Comment: I mean I'm in the directory above my package, not the package directory. Editing to make it clear

Comment: It is also often helpful to show more of the actual error message.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. Missing `__init__.py`

Answer (score 6):

I was missing the file `<my-package>/__init__.py`, so technically  wasn't actually a Python package. It did have an `__main__.py` file, which was why the command `python -m <my-package>` still worked.

Comment: Actually, [this is a bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1645), in that it does not support PEP420 namespace packages

Comment: It does now. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html?highlight=namespace#mapping-file-paths-to-modules

Answer (score 1):

I found that in a source tree like

```
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── src
    └── ns
        └── pkg
            └── __init__.py
```

with the following pyproject.toml*:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "test-pkg"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "meh"
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
packages = [{include = "ns", from = "src"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
mypy = "^1.6.1"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.mypy]
packages = ["ns.pkg"]
```

I'd get

```
$ poetry run mypy
Can't find package 'ns.pkg'
```

but if I added `py.typed` to the package:

```
$ > src/ns/pkg/py.typed
$ poetry run mypy
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Likewise

```
src
└── ns
    └── pkg.py
```

fails, but

```
src
└── ns
    ├── pkg.py
    └── py.typed
```

passes.

*note: I don't believe that it matters that I'm using poetry here. I believe mypy's behavior would be the same in any environment where the package is on the pythonpath, with respect to the existence of py.typed.